# Android : Notify AsyncTask when another AsyncTask is completed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a activity which performs 2 HTTP requests through 2 AsyncTask classes.The parameters to second HTTP request is filled by the result of first HTTP request so I want to start the second HTTP request after the first AsyncTask class execution is completed.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Start the second `AsyncTask` from first's `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Why don't you start the second once the first one finishes, or even do both network calls on the same AsyncTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample**

Start the `FirstTask` in your `Activity`

```
class FirstTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        new SecondTask().execute();
    }

}
```

---

```
class SecondTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```